# How to handle upload folder in git & wordpress devlopment workflow

Tags: wordpress, git, gitignore

I am currently learning use git & wordpress development workflow:

1. develop the wp site locally in mamp enviroment;
2. push the local wp repo to the remote repo in my serve;
3. use git hook to automatically push the repo in my server to server site folder;

but there is a problem in this workflow, if the user upload a file in my live site, the server repo could not push to the live server, as I have to stash those "avatar files" through ssh.

My need is to push my local site to remote server and every will be merger automatically.

How could I do that?

btw, this is my gitignore file :

```
*.log
.htaccess
/local-config.php
/sql-dump-*.sql
/wp-content/cache/*
.DS_Store
/shared/content/uploads/wp-sync-db
/wp-content/advanced-cache.php
/wp-content/wp-cache-config.php
/wp-content/backup-db/
/wp-content/backups/
/wp-content/upgrade/
/wp-content/cache/
sitemap.xml
sitemap.xml.gz
Thumbs.db
[http] 
    postBuffer = 524288000
```

sorry about my English, hope I make things clear...

Comment: gitignore your uploads folder in its entirety. Treat the live site as canonical for user added content, same goes for the database.

Comment: Thanks for you help.  But I have add uploads folder in my live site, and If I use "git rm -r --cache .." and add uploads foloder into my gitignore files in my local repo and then push it to remote repo, all the upload files in my live site will be removed, how could I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Updating your index should solve the issue.
Docs [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html).

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged  uploads/user-uploaded-content
```